# Unlist all lists from dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x

I have a column from dataframe that looks something like this:

```
[[20164401, nan], [26817203, nan], [50584001, nan]]
[[65829601, nan], [07935501, nan]]
[[87959305, [08678501, 47896001, 73737327]]
```

How can I unlist all of the lists in the row and if it's possible to remove the 'nan'?
The expected output is:

```
    [20164401, 26817203, 50584001]
    [65829601, 07935501]
    [87959305, 08678501, 47896001, 73737327]
```

I tried with `new_mass_whitelist2 = new_mass_whitelist1.applymap(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x)` ,but  is not working as expected, because there are still unlisted lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your DF to try on, but as long as the values are `int` and `np.nan` something similar to this should work:

```
new_mass_whitelist2 = new_mass_whitelist1.apply(lambda x: [j for i in x for j in i if j!=np.nan])
```

If the data is all strings you will change the `np.nan` for `'nan'` and add `lower()` if you want it to be a litle flexible with NaN or nan,

```
new_mass_whitelist2 = new_mass_whitelist1.apply(lambda x: [j for i in x for j in i if j.lower()!='nan'])
```

Comment: The values are strings, I am not sure for the nan. This code is giving me NaN on every row.

Comment: Actually, the first code did the job, but inside the unnested lists there are still nan's.

Comment: When I try the second code it gives me `'float' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: All fixed with `.apply(lambda x: [j for i in x for j in i if type(j) is not float])`

Comment: ah, you can also use `np.isnan()` or `str(j).lower()!='nan'`